# Jekyll overwriting existing files

Tags: frameworks, jekyll

I am a beginner in using jekyll. Every time I enter Jekyll serve'in the command line, it auto generates the default jekyll filesand completely overwrites my own personal files. How do I stop it from doing it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Comment: I guess that you're talking about files in `_site` folder ?

Answer (score 3):

Jekyll will generate files to the _site folder, except you have changed the _site location in the _config.yml file.

The trick with Jekyll is it will take everything from your source folders, except the folders which start with an _ and build the website out of them to _site.

If this is your layout:

```
index.html
css/style.css
img/pic.jpg
```

Jekyll will use these files, check if there something to process, and put the output to _site:

```
_site/index.html
_site/css/style.css
_site/img/pic.jpg
```

That said, you should not edit inside your _site folder. Edit the content outside the _site folder.

Here is [more details](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/).

Please note, that when you do not want a few folders to be part of your Jekyll build, you can ignore them like that in your _config.yml:

```
exclude: [Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, README.md]
```

Also note that some files are not processed correctly when they do not contain a Frontmatter. You can [read more about that here](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/).